# How do I install and activate the ZipArchive extension for RedHat 8 for PHP 7.4?

Tags: php, linux, reference, zip

**CONTEXT.** Red Hat 8, PHP 7.4

**PROBLEM.** The Wordpress Duplicator plugin tells me that Zip Compression is disabled: *Fail: The ZipArchive extension is mandatory*

**HOW I HAVE TRIED TO SOLVE**

I run `yum info zip` to make sure the ZIP extension is installed:

```
Installed Packages
Name         : zip
Version      : 3.0
Release      : 23.el8
Architecture : x86_64
Size         : 823 k
Source       : zip-3.0-23.el8.src.rpm
Repository   : @System
From repo    : anaconda
Summary      : A file compression and packaging utility compatible with PKZIP
URL          : http://www.info-zip.org/Zip.html
License      : BSD
Description  : The zip program is a compression and file packaging utility.  Zip is
             : analogous to a combination of the UNIX tar and compress commands and
             : is compatible with PKZIP (a compression and file packaging utility for
             : MS-DOS systems).
             : Install the zip package if you need to compress files using the zip
             : program.
```

There are many posts with this same problem and in many they give the solution to install the extension using `yum install php-pecl-zip`. Which does not work for me, because it returns: **Error: No matching Packages to list**

I have run `yum search zip` to see what packages are available and it returns this:

```
----------- Name & Summary Matched: zip
zip.x86_64 : A file compression and packaging utility compatible with PKZIP
bzip2-devel.i686 : Libraries and header files for apps which will use bzip2
bzip2-devel.x86_64 : Libraries and header files for apps which will use bzip2
bzip2-libs.x86_64 : Libraries for applications using bzip2
bzip2-libs.i686 : Libraries for applications using bzip2
nbdkit-gzip-plugin.x86_64 : GZip file serving plugin for nbdkit
nbdkit-plugin-gzip.x86_64 : GZip file serving plugin for nbdkit
perl-Archive-Zip.noarch : Perl library for accessing Zip archives
perl-Compress-Bzip2.x86_64 : Interface to Bzip2 compression library
perl-Compress-Raw-Bzip2.x86_64 : Low-level interface to bzip2 compression library
unzip.x86_64 : A utility for unpacking zip files
zziplib.i686 : Lightweight library to easily extract data from zip files
zziplib.x86_64 : Lightweight library to easily extract data from zip files
zziplib-utils.x86_64 : Utilities for the zziplib library

----------- Name Matched: zip
bzip2.x86_64 : A file compression utility
gzip.x86_64 : The GNU data compression program
java-1.8.0-openjdk-javadoc-zip.noarch : OpenJDK 8 API documentation compressed in a single archive
java-11-openjdk-javadoc-zip.x86_64 : OpenJDK 11 API documentation compressed in a single archive

----------- Summary Matched: zip
pigz.x86_64 : Parallel implementation of gzip
```

**QUESTIONS**

1. I assume that the ZIP extension that I already have installed is for console use, general for the operating system, and something else is the zip extension for PHP, correct?
2. How do I install and activate the ZipArchive extension for RedHat 8 for PHP 7.4?

Comment: The `zip` package has nothing to do with PHP. The package you want is likely going to be something like `php-zip`.

Comment: I don't have a RedHat8 install handy but `php-pecl-zip` is the correct package name for Centos8 and Fedora34. You might try something like `yum search php | grep zip` to find the right package name.

Comment: Check `php-commons` `zip` support is there